# three.js ShaderMaterial FlatShading

Tags: three.js, glsl

I'm writing a custom ShaderMaterial and decided to include lights and fog. So far so good and I got the shader integrated with three.js build it fog, ambient and point lights (it serves my purpose).

However, the shading I get its smooth, not flat. Before you guys decide to suggest adding the `shading: THREE.FlatShading` flag to the ShaderMaterial, remember that this is a custom Shader and therefore that won't really do anything.

Since FlatShading is done by calculating the triangle centroid and fill all the colors based on that vector, I thought using the normal of the triangle vertices would do the trick.. obviously it doest... Is that a way of correctly have a FlatShading light where all the pixels inside the triangle have 1 single colour? If so, what am I missing?

here's my shader in CoffeeScript

class SomeShader

```
constructor: ->

    @defines = {}

    @uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge [
        THREE.UniformsLib['fog']
        THREE.UniformsLib['lights']
        {
            color: { type: 'c', value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) }
        }
    ]

    @vertex = [
        'uniform vec3 ambientLightColor;'
        '#if MAX_POINT_LIGHTS > 0'
        '   uniform vec3 pointLightColor[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];'
        '   uniform vec3 pointLightPosition[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];'
        '   uniform float pointLightDistance[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];'
        '#endif'

        'uniform vec3 color;'
        'varying vec4 v_color;'

        'void main() {'
        # lights
        '   vec3 norm = normalMatrix * normal;'
        '   vec3 pos = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(position-norm, 1.0 )).xyz;'
        '   vec3 outgoingLight = vec3(1.);'
        '   vec4 addedLights = vec4(0., 0., 0., 1.);'
        '   #if MAX_POINT_LIGHTS > 0'
        '   for(int l = 0; l < MAX_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {'
        '       vec3 lightDirection = normalize(pos - pointLightPosition[l]);'
        '       addedLights.rgb += clamp(dot(-lightDirection, norm), 0.0, 1.0) * pointLightColor[l];'
        '   }'
        '   #endif'
        '   addedLights += vec4(ambientLightColor, 1.);'
        '   v_color = vec4(outgoingLight, 1.) * addedLights;'
        '   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);'
        '}'
    ].join '\n'

    @fragment = [
        THREE.ShaderChunk['fog_pars_fragment']

        'varying vec4 v_color;'

        'void main() {'
        '   vec3 outgoingLight = vec3( 1. );'
            THREE.ShaderChunk['fog_fragment']
        '   gl_FragColor = v_color * vec4(outgoingLight, 1.);'
        '}'
    ].join '\n'
```

Comment: whats wrong with using just computeFaceNormals()?

Comment: I've tried to call ```geometry.computeFaceNormals()``` but does nothing...

Comment: I'm not sure what's the correct sequence but you might actually try applying flatshading, because it might control wether the normal attribute gets filled with face normals or vertex normals. Remember that regardless of this being a custom shader, you are still using a predefined attribute (position, uv, color, normal...)

Comment: I've tried adding the shading property with FlatShading to my shadermaterial but still no luck :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `ShaderMaterial` and your are displacing your vertices in the vertex shader with a noise function. You also want to recompute the vertex normals so the shading is flat -- i.e., faceted.

To do that, you need to compute new normals using screen-space derivatives in the fragment shader, and also do your lighting calculation in the fragment shader.

So, in your vertex shader, compute the following `varying`:

```
varying vec3 vViewPosition;

vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( displacedPosition, 1.0 );
vViewPosition = - mvPosition.xyz; // vector from vertex to camera
```

Then, in the fragment shader, compute the normal using screen-space derivatives:

```
normal = normalize( cross( dFdx( vViewPosition ), dFdy( vViewPosition ) ) );
```

Now, use your lighting model to compute the shading in the fragment shader.

three.js r.73

Comment: thanks for your reply. Its been very helpful and I did made some progress. However, as you can see from my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrevenancio/hr67e6kv/), there is something wrong with the light position... Any idea? @WestLangley ?

Comment: actually just fixed it. Thanks for all the help :)